# How to remove an area from HTML5 Map?

Tags: javascript

I have  tried to remove an area element from HTML5 map, there is my code:

```js
var target = $(e.target);
var targetId = target.attr('id');
$(targetId).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<map name="diffmap" id="diffmap">
 <area shape="circle" id="area1" coords="15,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area2" coords="123,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area3" coords="158,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area4" coords="1288,456,33">
</map>
```

its not remove the area, what can be the problem?

**EDIT:**
I fixed the problem, here what I do:

```
$(target).remove();
```

Instead of

```
$(targetId).remove();
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code also.

Comment: @Ashu See the question edit

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#diffmap").click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  var targetId = target.attr('id');
  console.log("Removing "+targetId);
  $(target).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzA2Ny8xNTkvb3JpZ2luYWwvcGxhbmV0MTAuanBn" width="250" height="250" alt="Planets" usemap="#diffmap">

<map name="diffmap" id="diffmap">
 <area shape="circle" id="area5" coords="0,0,100">
  <area shape="circle" id="area1" coords="15,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area2" coords="123,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area3" coords="158,456,33">
 <area shape="circle" id="area4" coords="1288,456,33">
</map>

<div id="log"></div>
```